# Prove groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $p \neq 2$ be a prime. Prove $U(p) = U(2p)$ and $U(p^2)=\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$.

I know $U(n)$ is the set of all classes x mod n relatively prime to $n$.

I know this statement is true, it is quite obvious, but I am having trouble proving it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the obvious map $U(2p) \to U(p)$ that sends $x \bmod 2p$ to $x \bmod p$.

This map is well defined, surjective, and a group homomorphism.

Since $U(2p)$ and $U(p)$ have the same number of elements, the map is an isomorphism.